# How to replace fragment properly using navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am using navigation drawer and it is simple to use. I am not providing the complete code but providing you detail which could be easy for you to understand my problem. I am using fragments these are about 8 in numbers and I am replacing them with one an other. But here comes a problem 
I am replacing them on click event of the navigation drawer. but there are two main problems

1. After replacement , I can see the previous fragment in the background. does replace method just call the new fragment over it ?  if yes then what should I do to old fragment not be visible in the background of my new fragment.
2. When I click navigation drawer Item , it loads the specific fragment successfully. but keeping in that fragment when I click to that specific item again it loads this fragment again and again. For example if drawer item num 3 opens fragment MyBook , then by clicking item num three 2 or many times would open fragment that much time.

So please some one answer me how to cure my app for such kind of actions which I described above.

Answer (score 1):

I tried like this. Its working fine me

```
    FragmentManager frgmanager = getFragmentManager();
    frgmanager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    FragmentTransaction frgTransaction = frgmanager.beginTransaction();

    if(subitem.equalsIgnoreCase("subitem")){
        Frag1 frg1 =new Frag1(mCtx);
        frgTransaction.replace(R.id.inflate_layout, frg1);
    }else if(subitem1.equalsIgnoreCase("subitem1")){
        Frag2 frg2 =new Frag2(mCtx);
        frgTransaction.replace(R.id.inflate_layout, frg2);
    }else{
        Frag2 frg3 =new Frag3(mCtx);
        frgTransaction.replace(R.id.inflate_layout, frg3);
    }
    frgTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    frgTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: but how can I keep track to not to open the multiple instance of same fragment

Comment: it is giving error , on 
frgTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE); 
it says must be one of , fragmentTransaction, open , close , none , When i switch it to none or open or close , the  error goes away

Comment: try without that line and check,  is Fragment calling or not

Answer (score 1):

you can use addtobackstack in fragmentstranstion object.like

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.bodyfragment, new AnotherFragment()); 
transaction.addtoBackStack(null).commit();
```

Comment: backstack is not helping me

Answer (score 0):

Use *replace*-method of FragmentTransaction instead of *add* (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions)

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.bodyfragment, new AnotherFragment()); 
transaction.commit();
```

To avoid re-instantiating the fragment, keep track of the current open fragment and only do a fragment transaction, if we next-to-be-opened fragment is a different one than the current.
This may achieved like the following:

```
class MyActivity ... {
  private String currentFragment;

  private void openNewFragment(Fragment fragment) {
      String newFragment = fragment.getClass().getSimpleName();

      if (newFragment.equals(currentFragment)){
          // new fragment already shown
          return;
      }
      // Fragment transaction etc here:
  }
}
```

Note that this only compares fragments based in their class name. Sometimes this might not be unique, e.g. if there is a DetailFragment class which displays information about an entity. Which entities details to show may depend on intent arguments.

The above code however will then prevent opening DetailFragment for Entity=1 if currently details for Entity=2 are shown. For these scenarios the information about the fragment kept needs to be extended (e.g. storing a Reference or [WeakReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) to the fragment instance itself).

Comment: Yes I am replacing , as I said it clearly in my above statements

Comment: how can I keep track on it ?

Comment: what is current fragment in it ?